# Restricted user profile not available on my Android 6 tablet. How come?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, tablet

A few weeks ago about an Archos 101b Helium tablet. It runs Android 6 (Marshmallow). Further specs [here](https://www.archos.com/us/products/tablets/helium/archos_101bhelium/index.html).

I've setup the tablet with a user and I now want to create an additional restricted user. When creating a new user it should normally ask if I want to create a normal or restricted profile. This however doesn't happen and I can only create normal users.

What could be the issue? I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931008/why-cant-i-create-a-restricted-profile-when-an-owner-device-app-is-set) talking about "owner device app", but I can't really find what it is on my tablet.

Answer (score 0):

The tablets I had were 4G tablets. Android considers those devices as phone devices on which the retsricted user accounts are not available.

I've used McAfee Mobile Security to restrict access to apps. Works very well!